# How can I launch apps or execute terminal commands in an Ubuntu 20.04.3 Docker container running on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: shell, docker, google-cloud

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04.3 desktop in the cloud on Google Cloud Run. When I run the container image locally, I can run any process, including a bash terminal.

However, on Google Cloud Run, connected via noVNC, I am unable to launch a terminal or any other process other than Google Chrome.  So I tried a couple different browser based terminal solutions, and here's what I found:

#### Using Spawn in Node.js

Using spawn, and a reverse shell node.js webserver, I can pass terminal commands. For instance, localhost:xxxx/exec?q=ls, would list files in the current working directory. I can also execute commands.

#### WebSSH2 and shellinabox

Both of these solutions use SSH to connect a browser client to an SSH server.  I can login to it, but when I run any command, I get the following output:

```
root@localhost:~# ls

[1] stopped            ls --color=auto
root@localhost:~# ls
```

As you can see, I even tried SSH as root, but still I'm unable to run any commands unless I use Node.js's spawn method to execute a shell command.

For context, here is what it looks like running Ubuntu, fluxbox, xvfb, and accessing the desktop via the browser using noVNC, locally. Note that, locally, everything works, and I can run `ls` in my home folder and see what files are there:

[image: Ubuntu Desktop container image via noVNC]

And this is what I see when running the same image in Google Cloud Run. Note that the `ls` command just returns `stopped [1]`:

[image: On Google Cloud Run and commands won't execute]

Here is what it looks like with the Node.js reverse shell. Here we can see that I can run `ls` in the /usr/bin folder. This is the only way I've been able to poke around the file system and see what permissions are set and execute commands on a container running in Google Cloud Run:

[image: On Google Cloud Run and commands can execute via a Node.js reverse shell]

Even if I use the Node.js reverse proxy to relax permissions on the files `chmod -R 777 /usr` I still cannot execute commands like `ls` when using WebSSH2 or shellinabox.

**What might be preventing shell commands and processes from running, even as root?**

Comment: Eg. executables being from another architecture. Eg. basic library missing or not found. Did you try the "unminimize"?

Comment: Hi @GerardH.Pille Not sure I follow what you're saying.  If it helps, the container image is built on an x86_64 Debian 11 Virtual Machine and pushed to Google Cloud Run, which is also x86_64.  The architectures are the same.  I'm viewing the running container via a browser on a Mac.

Comment: Did you follow what the welcome message tells you?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I ran 'unminimize' from the reverse shell. No prompt appears to ask if I'd like to proceed.  Like other commands, I just get "stopped" if trying to run from a terminal connected via SSH.  Also, I see the same welcome message when running the container image locally, yet everything works, without unminimize.

Comment: Google Cloud says they have "expert support".  Can't they help you?